# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint Django Python

Tags: python, django

My goal. If the id matches, you need to update the creation time column in the model.
I can't figure out how I can solve this problem.
It doesn't seem complicated, but I'm stuck.

```
if a:=Defect.objects.get(id_leather=id_file_name) == True:
    a.update(created=datetime.datetime.now())
else:
    Defect.objects.create(id_leather=id_file_name, path=path_file_save)
```

`models.py`

```
class Defect(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "files_defect_id_leather_key"
DETAIL:  Key (id_leather)=(9998) already exists.
```

Comment: please share the complete `Defect` model structure

Comment: I suggest using update_or_create feature of Django. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

Comment: @JyothiS class Defect(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_leather = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True, null=False, default=1)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    result_auto = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    result_manual = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)

Comment: Please don't modify the question after trying one of the answers. Leave the original question as it is to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `== True` from your condition. `a` is not a boolean, it's a `Defect` instance. It can never be equal to `True`:

```
if a:=Defect.objects.get(id_leather=id_file_name):
```

Also you can't `.update()` individual model instances. Use

```
a.created = datetime.datetime.now()
a.save()
```

That being said, consider using [`update_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) for such workflows. Your method is prone to *race conditions*, i.e. another process can create the same `Defect` instance while you are still processing the `else` part.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I solved my problem:

```
import datetime
created_date = datetime.datetime.now()
Defect.objects.update_or_create(id_leather=id_file_name, path=path_file_save, defaults={'created': created_date})
```